# Android style - difference between @style, android:, @android:style, etc

Tags: android, android-styles

In android developer examples, blogs, etc, I have seen multiple prefixes for the values of style attributes. Can someone please describe when to use what? For example, what is the difference between these 3 cases?

```
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance"
parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat"
parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
```

What is the difference between these 2 cases?

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any prefix references the style named on the same file.

**@Style** references your *style.xml* project file.

**@android:style** references defined *Android API* style.

More about [Style Resource](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and [Style and Themes](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

About [*colorControlNormal*](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/R.attr.html#colorControlNormal) vs *android:colorControlNormal* is the same explanation. If you use **controlColorNormal** you are defining the color applied to framework controls in their normal state in you app. If you use  **android:colorControlNormal** you are overwriting the the color default applied to framework controls by the system.

Comment: This is not true for AppCompat.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of @ as signaling that a named resource is coming up.

`@type/name` identifies a resource of type `type` (string, color, layout, style etc) with name `name` defined in the app is coming up.

`@+id/name` identifies an id resource called `name` that will be created if it doesn't already exist (whereas @id simply refers to an id that already exists).

`@android:type/name` means that the named resource is part of the Android platform is coming up (it's *not* defined in the app -- it's provided by the device).

For style parents, the @style is optional.  You can refer to styles directly by name.  It's redundant because you can't derive a style from anything other than another style anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on the colorControlNormal vs android:colorControlNormal part. Which should I use in my style.xml?

Comment: It's not about which one you *should* use, it's about identifying the correct one for your case.  If it's a resource you defined yourself, then just use that name.  If it's something defined by the Android platform, you need the android prefix.